# Infinite loop when generating URL of GET request with Requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

My goal is to generate the URL of a GET request to an API. The following code results in the error message "The program took too long to finish. Check your code for infinite loops."

```
import requests

query_params = { 'apikey': 'API_KEY',
                 'phrase': 'fiscal cliff'
               }

endpoint = 'http://capitolwords.org/api/text.json'
response = requests.get(endpoint, params = query_params)

request_url = response.url
print request_url
```

Comment: I think you've missed something, because I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: There is nothing in your sample code that would ordinarily cause an infinite loop. Please do include the *full* error message including traceback in your post.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the code producing the error you complain of. Not only is there no infinite loop (indeed no loop in your code at all), running the code works in so far as it results in a 401 response (because the request requires authentication).